# Using BeautifulSoup to extract specific dl and dd list elements

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, extract

My first time posting.  I am using BeautifulSoup 4 and python 2.7 (pycharm). I have a webpage containing    elements and I need to extract specific  elements where the  tags are either 'Salary:' or 'Date:', the page contains multiple lists .

The problem: I cannot seem to identify and extract specific text.  I have searched this site and tried without success.

Example html:

```
<dl><dt>Date:</dt><dd>13 September 2015</dd><dt>Salary:</dt><dd>Starting at £40,130 per annum.</dd></dl><dl><dt>Date:</dt><dd>15 December 2015</dd><dt>Salary:</dt><dd>Starting at £22,460 per annum.</dd></dl><dl><dt>Date:</dt><dd>10 January 2014</dd><dt>Salary:</dt><dd>Starting at £18,160 per annum.</dd></dl>
```

Code which I have tried without success:

```
r = requests.get("http://www.mywebsite.com/test.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
dl_data = soup.find_all("dl")
for dlitem in dl_data: 
    print dlitem.find("dt",text="Date:").parent.findNext("dd").contents[0]
    print dlitem.find("dt",text="Salary:").parent.findNext("dd").contents[0]
```

Expected Result:

```
13 September 2015
15 December 2015
10 January 2014
Starting at £40,130 per annum.
Starting at £22,460 per annum.
Starting at £18,160 per annum.
```

Actual Result:

```
print dlitem.find("dt",text="Date:").parent.findNext("dd").contents[0]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parent'
```

I have tried numerous variations of this code and gone round in circles, I figured out how to print out all dd elements to screen, just not specific dd elements!

Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Updating the `print`s to use 3.x print function calls, I don't get any exception messages. I also get the output in a different order from what's shown as expected here, but that makes perfect sense because of how the loop is written - if that's what the question is about, it's a typo. I also see each date twice instead of the salaries, but that also has an obvious cause - both `dt` tags have the same parent `dl` tag, so of course `.findNext('dd')` finds the date text both times. I would also consider that a typo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If order is not important just make some changes:

```
...
dl_data = soup.find_all("dd")
for dlitem in dl_data:
    print dlitem.string
```

Result:

```
13 September 2015
Starting at £40,130 per annum.
15 December 2015
Starting at £22,460 per annum.
10 January 2014
Starting at £18,160 per annum.
```

For your latest request:

```
for item in list(zip(soup.find_all("dd")[0::3],soup.find_all("dd")[2::3])):
    date, salary = item
    print ', '.join([date.string, salary.string])
```

Output:

```
13 September 2015, 100
14 September 2015, 200
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, but do you know how to identify by string Salary:  Date: The example I gave above was simple some examples I have contain other code that I do not need so your example will extract all dd and I need specific dd text extracting. Thanks

Comment: BeautifulSoup is able to get a lot of information. Please provide data in and data out (exactly how you would like to get it) for your example(s)

Comment: Another example as requested  <dl><dt>Date:</dt><dd>13 September 2015</dd><dt>Post:</dt><dd>Programmer</dd><dt>Salary:</dt><dd>100</dd><dt>Date:</dt><dd>14 September 2015</dd><dt>Post:</dt><dd>Database Admin</dd><dt>Salary:</dt><dd>200</dd></dl>  in this example I would only want date and salary information but not the post information, so my expected output would be "13 September 2015","100","14 September 2015","200" the text "Database Admin" and "Programmer" would not be displayed.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I guess it works if you just omit the `.parent` in your code. At least this worked for my problem which is very similar to yours.

Here's my html, where order of the `<dt>` is not guaranteed:

```
<dl>
 <dt>Time</dt><dd>10:05:02</dd>
 <dt>Temp</dt><dd>20.5°C</dd>
</dl>
```

I'm accessing the values successfully with the following code:

```
 time = at_tl.find("dt",text="Time").findNext("dd").string
 temp = at_tl.find("dt",text="Temp").findNext("dd").string
```

Answer (score 2):

A more robust solution would be to make a `dict` of  (key,value) pairs of all (dt,dd) elements in the dl. Then select the desired fields from the dict.

---

### How to convert a 'dl' element to a dict

Data in some class "obj":

```
html = """
    <dl class="obj">
      <dt>Time</dt> <dd>10:00</dd>
      <dt>Temp</dt> <dd>20.5°C</dd>
    </dl>  
       """
```

Save all the "dt" aand "dl" then zip them to form a dict:

```
def get_dl(soup):
    keys, values = [], []
    for dl in soup.findAll("dl", {"class": "obj"}):
        for dt in dl.findAll("dt"):
            keys.append(dt.text.strip())
        for dd in dl.findAll("dd"):
            values.append(dd.text.strip())
    return dict(zip(keys, values))

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
dl_dict = get_dl(soup)
```

Outputs:

```
{'Time': '10:00', 'Temp': '20.5°C'}
```