# Parse html description (dt/dd) with python

Tags: html, python-3.x, parsing

I need to parse a bunch of html pages (the description only) to a table.
How I can do that?

While I am trying:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
r = requests.get('http://images.webofknowledge.com/WOK46/help/WOS/Y_abrvjt.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
dl_data = soup.find_all("dd")
# print(dl_data)
for dlitem in dl_data:
    print(dlitem.string)
```

Which gives me the "dd" as expected, mysteriously, `soup.find_all("dt")` is yelding `None`. But, most importantly, I need to parse them together, and put it in a single table.

Please Help.

[This is the SO discussion I have followed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475700/using-beautifulsoup-to-extract-specific-dl-and-dd-list-elements)

**Update**: Do you mean something like:

```
for dlitem in dl_data:
    print(dlitem)
    print("\n\n\n")
```

But this does not change anything(except, dd tag is present now). May be, I was not explicit enough, but what I want is, say, for the item in html:

```
 </B><DT>YALE JOURNAL OF BIOLOGY AND MEDICINE
<B><DD> YALE J BIOL MED
```

I want to get it in two column table, as:

```
# ======== COL 1  =========             ====COL 2 =====
YALE JOURNAL OF BIOLOGY AND MEDICINE    YALE J BIOL MED
```

Comment: That's some impressively [awful, broken rubbish](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fimages.webofknowledge.com%2FWOK46%2Fhelp%2FWOS%2FY_abrvjt.html) that you're trying to parse there.

Comment: Change the last line there to     `print(dlitem)
    print("\n\n\n")` (on two lines). The HTML is so broken that BS isn't parsing it properly.

Comment: @Quentin: Please can you see the edit?

Comment: You missed my point. I made a comment (to point out that you are dealing with invalid HTML and that your parser is not coping well with it). I did not post an answer with a solution. If I did, it would have appeared below, with the answers.